# SharePoint not recognizing few users

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, user

I am using SharePoint Online. I am trying to invite one Internal user to my SharePoint site but SharePoint is not recognizing that user. If I try to find that user using his email address then SharePoint is giving me message that `xyz@xyz.com is outside of your organisation`.

This is an old user. when I go to 'SharePoint Admin Center' and search this user in 'User Profiles' then I can see this user. That means user is valid and successfully synced with SharePoint.

Any idea why SharePoint cannot find this user when I am trying to share my site with him?

Thanks

Comment: A farm is composed by WebApplications and these are composed by Sites. Each site has user which are allowed to access it. Could it be you are looking for a user on a site where this user is not granted to access?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set permissions for internal user you can set them directly to SharePoint Group or as User Permission in Site Permission (Site Settings) you don't need to use Share functionality for inviting him.

But you can try:

1. Look to **Office 365 Admin** center and **Users**, if there is some identity
   of this User with **#EXT#** attribute. If yes, delete this user
2. Go to **SharePoint Admin Center > Profiles** > Search this user, if is
   here too, delete it.
3. Go to **Site Collection** where is problem, open **All Users Table**: https://company.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0 find this user here, delete it too.
4. Synchronize correct user to AAD, **wait a day**, try to invite him again.

*Hope it helps!*